# Is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!!} x^{k!}$ non-elementary?

Tags: elementary-functions

Is $z \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k!)!} z^{k!}$ an elementary function? I designed it to be analytic but analogous to Liouville's constant, but don't know how to search for this function.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but $k!!$ denotes the double factorial and not the iterated factorial $(k!)!$? Anyway, it is a lacunary series, and elementary functions don't have lacunary series. [_Waits for somebody to point out an elementary function I haven't heard of yet._]

Comment: @DanielFischer: I knew of the double factorial but thought it would be obvious what I meant. Anyway why do elementary functions not have lacunary series?

Comment: I don't know why, it is just the case that elementary functions (trigonometric functions, hyperbolic functions, exponentials, logarithms, powers [including roots], polynomials, rational functions of these, compositions of these) happen to not have lacunary series [to the best of my knowledge].

Comment: @DanielFischer: Wait I just checked up on lacunary series. They aren't analytic, but isn't my function analytic?

Comment: I used "lacunary series" in the loose sense that the gaps between non-zero terms grow sufficiently fast. If the coefficients converge to $0$ fast enough, that can of course still give entire functions. If the coefficients converge too slowly to $0$ or not at all, then you have a function with natural boundary on its circle of convergence.

Comment: Well, $0$ is surely an elementary function, and it has a lacunary series... sorry, heh.